# javascript variable text color

Tags: javascript, variables, colors

I'm trying to add color to a string javascript variable but it outputs thecode instead

what I have is

```
var str  = "COLORME RED ";
str  += "COLORMENOT ";
```

i tried

```
var col = "COLORME";
var colored = col.fontcolor("#ff0000");
var str = colored + " RED ";
str  += "COLORMENOT ";
```

but instead of getting

```
**COLORME** RED COLORMENOT
```

NOTE: **COLORME** is red

what i get is

```
<font color="#ff0000">COLORME</font> RED COLORMENOT
```

thanks in advance

Comment: `var colored = col.fontcolor("#ff0000:);`?

Comment: just a typo when writing the question. doesn't solve the issue

Comment: The question is a bit confusing to me, could you create a jsfiddle or explain e bit more ? What is the HTML you'd expect ?

Answer (score 0):

[`String.prototype.fontcolor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fontcolor)

> **Usage note:** The [`<font>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) element has been removed in HTML5 and shouldn't
>   be used anymore. Instead web developers should use CSS properties.

---

Proper usage of the DOM is key. Use `style` tags, not `font` tags.

```
<p><span style="color:#FF0000;">COLORME</span> RED COLORMENOT</p>
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/W6xc5/)</kbd>

```
(function () {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    var s = document.createElement('span');
    var t = document.createTextNode();

    s.style.color = '#FF0000';

    s.innerHTML = 'COLORME';
    t.nodeValue = ' RED COLORMENOT';

    p.appendChild(s);
    p.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(p);
})();
```